# Relationship between scalar and vector valued automorphic forms

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, adeles

Let $F$ be a number field with signature $(r_1,r_2)$. There are two definitions of automorphic forms on $GL_{2,F}$ that I am aware of. Let $K=O_2(\mathbb R)^{r_1}\times U_2(\mathbb C)^{r_2}$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $GL_2(F)$. Roughly speaking, the two definitions are

Definition 1 (scalar valued): An automorphic form is a smooth function $f:GL_2(\mathbb A_F)\to \mathbb C$ that is left $GL_2(F)$-invariant, right $K$ finite, ... Denote the space of all such functions by $\mathcal A$.

Definition 2 (vector valued): Fix an irreducible representation $(\rho,V)$ of $K$. An automorphic form (of weight $V$) is a smooth function $f:GL_2(\mathbb A_F)\to V$ that is left $GL_2(F)$-invariant, $f(gk)=\rho(k)^{-1}f(g)$ for all $g\in GL_2(\mathbb A_F),k\in K,$... Denote the space of all such functions by $\mathcal A(\rho)$.

May I ask what is the relationship between these two notions? For instance, will a statement like $\mathcal A\cong \oplus_{\rho} \mathcal A(\rho)\otimes_{\mathbb C} V^\vee$, where $\rho$ runs over the isomorphism classes of finite dimensional irreducible representations of $K$, holds?

Also, given $f\in \mathcal A(\rho)$, how should one define the automorphic representation (which should be an irreducible subquotient of some space of scalar valued functions) associated to it?